# Spark remove Duplicate cell values and

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to remove a duplicate cell values in a column but keep cell empty. Following is my input

```
//+---+---+---+
//|  x|  y|  z|
//+---+---+---+
//|  1| 45| 45|
//|  1| 67| 67|
//|  1| 43| 43|
//|  2| 45| 45|
//|  2| 67| 67|
//+---+---+---+
```

It should be converted to

```
//+---+---+---+
//|  x|  y|  z|
//+---+---+---+
//|  1| 45| 45|
//|   | 67| 67|
//|   | 43| 43|
//|  2| 45| 45|
//|   | 67| 67|
//+---+---+---+
```

Thanks

Comment: can you remove the image and actual text data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window **`lag`** function and if `lag value` is not null then replace it with **`lit("")`**.

```
//input data
df.show()
//+---+---+---+
//|  x|  y|  z|
//+---+---+---+
//|  1| 45| 45|
//|  1| 67| 67|
//|  1| 43| 43|
//|  2| 45| 45|
//|  2| 67| 67|
//+---+---+---+

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val window = lag(col("x"), 1).over(Window.partitionBy("x"))
df.withColumn("lag",window).withColumn("x", when(col("lag").isNotNull,lit("")).otherwise(col("x"))).show()

//result
//+---+---+---+
//|  x|  y|  z|
//+---+---+---+
//|  1| 45| 45|
//|   | 67| 67|
//|   | 43| 43|
//|  2| 45| 45|
//|   | 67| 67|
//+---+---+---+
```

---

In case if you don't want to use `.isNotNull` in case statement then:

```
//if lag value is null then replaced by -99999
val window = lag(col("x"), 1,-99999).over(Window.partitionBy("x"))

df.withColumn("lag",window).withColumn("x", when(col("lag") !== -99999,lit("")).otherwise(col("x"))).drop("lag").show()

//+---+---+---+
//|  x|  y|  z|
//+---+---+---+
//|  1| 45| 45|
//|   | 67| 67|
//|   | 43| 43|
//|  2| 45| 45|
//|   | 67| 67|
//+---+---+---+
```

Comment: What happens the column values of X are dynamically changing not always 1 or 2 etc..

Comment: @rakeeee, Still it will work, we will create partition based on `X` column and keep `X` column value only for first record, rest will be replaced as `empty string`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that uses the `row_number` function. It does not require the `lag` function that should specify the range but still, I also need the temporary column. Either way is the same complexity I think.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w = Window.partitionBy("X").orderBy("tempid")
df.withColumn("tempid", monotonically_increasing_id)
  .withColumn("X", when(row_number.over(w) === 1, col("X")).otherwise(lit("")))
  .drop("tempid")
  .show(false)
```

The result is:

```
+---+---+---+
|X  |Y  |Z  |
+---+---+---+
|1  |45 |45 |
|   |67 |67 |
|   |43 |43 |
|   |42 |42 |
|2  |45 |45 |
|   |2  |2  |
|   |43 |43 |
|   |1  |1  |
+---+---+---+
```